The 'Pods-PromoSuite' target has frameworks with conflicting names: ppriskmagnes.xcframework
Ios Swift
While integrating the Braintree SDK into our project, we encountered the following error:" The 'Pods-PromoSuite' target has frameworks with conflicting names: ppriskmagnes.xcframework".
Our project already includes the iZettleSDK pod, which also depends on ppriskmagnes.xcframework. Since both Braintree and iZettleSDK include this framework, it’s causing a conflict during installation.
Could you please guide us on how to resolve this conflict or suggest an alternative way to include both Braintree and iZettleSDK in the same project?
Need to use both sdk

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
